# Why does kivy show me a white background instead of the real rgba number?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In this program i set the background color of `Label` to `6, 61, 81, 1`  like this :

```
        background_color: 6, 61, 81, 1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:self.background_color
```

but in the out put kivy show me white background.

[image: code]

So I can not see the actual color that I set.

code :

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle 

Builder.load_string("""
    

<grid>
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width,root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: 33
                text:'1'
                background_color: 6, 61, 81, 1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:self.background_color
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                        
            TextInput:
                multiline:False
                height: 33
                size_hint: (5, None)
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                foreground_color: 87, 30, 59, 0.8
                
            










""")

class grid(Widget):
    pass

class foo(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor='#1618388'
        return grid()




    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo().run()
```

However i set the `rgba` value to `1,0,0,1` it showed me correctly.

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Equivalently (to the given answer) you can use the function `rgba` keeping all the values as, `background_color: rgba(6, 61, 81, 1)` (where all values are in 0-255 range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing 8-bit integer RGB values, i.e. integers from 0 to 255 where 255 is fully saturated.

Kivy's API uses floating point RGB values in the range 0-1.

To convert from your units to those that Kivy expects, divide your RGB values by 255.